# The asymptotic order of the series of function terms

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I want to know the order of $ \sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\frac{{\sqrt n }}{{{{\left( {\ln n} \right)}^n}}}{x^n}} $ when $ x \to  + \infty  $, or a fine upper bound. I appreciate any good ideas or solutions!

Comment: *You want to know ....*. Good, but we would like to know what **you** already tried.

Comment: I guess we can use some integral transformations to replace logarithms, so as to get the elementary summable part, and then use Laplace method to estimate the order. However, I haven't find that. I mainly want to ask if anyone has seen similar conclusions. Thank you very much!

Comment: This does not answer my question. How do you want some help if we do not know what you already tried (even if it totally failed) and where you are stuck.

Comment: I have solved the problem myself, thanks for your concern! The main idea is to consider the Taylor series of exp(exp (x ^ (1/2))) and to do some asymptotic analysis of the general term.

Comment: This is interesting and good to know. I suppose that the order is quite high; is it correct ? Cheers :-)

Comment: Yeah, the order seems to be quite high, but lower than exp(exp(x^a)) with any a>0. Unfortunately, I did not find the exact order.

Comment: Would an empirical approach be acceptable ?

Comment: Yes, but it requires some complicated asymptotic analysis. As this is an intermediate conjecture of my work, I'm afraid it can't be made public for the time being :(